# Deallocation error [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator initWithManagedObjectModel]

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

When creating the `persistentStoreCoordinator` the call to `addPersistentStoreWithType` crashes.  Debugging with Zombies reveals an deallocation error

> -[NSRelationshipDescription name]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e5fd0f50

I noticed that the `NSManagedObjectModel` is created successfully (printed to console) however as soon as the `PersistentStoreCoordinator` is inited with the model, trying to print the model object returns that same deallocated instance error.

I am using `SSDataKit` from *CocoaPods* but also moved the same code into my app delegate for testing with same results.  I have disabled optimizations and verified ARC is enabled.

Any ideas on what this may be?

**Mac 10.9.2 Xcode 5.1.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting this I found the issue.  My model had a relationship to a target object where the inverse relationship was defined in the parent entity.

Example:

Entity (relationship)
Foo (bars) -> Bar (foo)

Bar doesn't define foo – it's parent entity does.

CoreData doesn't signal a warning of any type, it just crashes from a deallocated relationship.

I updated my model in this way:
Foo (bars) -> Baz (foo)

and then provided a new set of accessors in the Bar to wrap the ones generated by CoreData in Baz.